# HOW to use STUFF with UPDATE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have table with 3 column and field Data-Types is Decimal(38,0).
so I want to update each row of my table . actually the length of number is not same as each other I mean some of them is 5 digit and some of them 7 digit but I want after 2 first digit insert '.' (Decimals) for example 123456 should be 12.3456

my table is:

```
+-------------+-------+-------+
| ID          |   X   |   Y   |
+-------------+-------+-------+
| 1200        | 321121| 345000| 
| 1201        | 564777| 4145  | 
| 1202        | 4567  | 121444| 
| 1203        | 12747 | 789887| 
| 1204        | 489899| 124778|
+-------------+-------+-------+
```

and I want to change this :

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
| ID          |   X    |   Y    |
+-------------+--------+--------+
| 1200        | 32.1121| 34.5000| 
| 1201        | 56.4777| 41.45  | 
| 1202        | 45.67  | 12.1444| 
| 1203        | 12.747 | 78.9887| 
| 1204        | 48.9899| 12.4778|
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

my code is here :

```
Update [dbo].[UTM]
     SET [X] = STUFF([X],3,0,'.')
         [Y] = STUFF([X],3,0,'.')
```

and I try this :

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE @COUNT1 int;
DECLARE @COUNT2 int;
DECLARE @TEMP_X VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @TEMP_Y VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @TEMP_main VARCHAR(255);

SELECT @COUNT1 = COUNT(*) FROM [UTM1];
SET @COUNT2 = 0;

    WHILE(@COUNT2<@COUNT1)
    BEGIN
        SET @TEMP_main = (SELECT [id] from [UTM1] order by [id] desc offset @COUNT2 rows fetch next 1 rows only);
        SET @TEMP_X = (SELECT [X] from [UTM1] order by [id] desc offset @COUNT2 rows fetch next 1 rows only);
        SET @TEMP_Y = (SELECT [Y] from [UTM1] order by [id] desc offset @COUNT2 rows fetch next 1 rows only);

        UPDATE [dbo].[UTM1]
           SET [X] = CONVERT(decimal(38,0),STUFF(@TEMP_X,3,0,'.'))
              ,[Y] = CONVERT(decimal(38,0),STUFF(@TEMP_Y,3,0,'.'))
           WHERE [id] = @TEMP_main;

        SET @COUNT2 = @COUNT2  +  1
    END

END
```

Comment: What is the data type of `x` and `y`?

Comment: What is the error with your actual code ?

Comment: @gordon-linoff decimal(38,0)

Comment: How do you know that 4145 represent 41.4500 and not 0.4145 ?  There is no way to distinguish those values.

Comment: You won't as it stands, be able to store any of those values in your column anyway, it's a `decimal(38,0)`, meaning it has a scale of 38 (it can hold numbers with up to 38 digits), with a precision of 0 (so to 0 decimal places). But why a `decimal(38,0)` do you *really* need to store (integer) numbers between ±99,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999? The data you've shown us looks like it would be better suited to something like a `decimal(6,4)`.

Comment: @Larnu you right, I should change my datatype

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `stuff()`-- your values don't look like strings they look like numbers.  You should be doing arithmetic operations.  However, if the columns are integers, you need to first convert them to an appropriate type:

```
alter table utm alter column x decimal(12, 4);
alter table utm alter column y decimal(12, 4);
```

Then do an update with division:

```
Update [dbo].[UTM]
     SET x = x / 10000
         y = y / 10000;
```

EDIT:

If the column is `decimal(38, 0)`, then you have no room for digits after the decimal points.  The `0` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

So, change the type of the column to allow digits.  The `(12, 4)` is a suggestion.  You can also use `(38, 4)` -- or many other combinations.

EDIT II:

You have a real problem with your data.  You can not tell if "1" should be 10.0000, 01.0000, 0.1000, 0.0100, 0.0010, or 0.0001.  I would suggest that you re-import the data using the correct type.

You *can* do the transformation -- after fixing the data types of the column.  One method is via strings (as you have attempted):

```
Update [dbo].[UTM]
     SET x = convert(decimal(12, 4), stuff(convert(varchar(255), x), 3, 0, '')),
         y = convert(decimal(12, 4), stuff(convert(varchar(255), y), 3, 0, ''))
```

However, I suspect that this is quite dangerous, because you may be missing leading zeros on your values and converting to the wrong value.  Numeric types in SQL do not store leading zeros.

Comment: bu the number is not same as each other for example some of them contain 5 digits and some of them 7

Comment: @JavadAbedi then why did you post sample data where all numbers had 4 decimal digits implying that this is the only case?

Comment: yeah I forgot this part of my question but now I Edit it

Comment: @JavadAbedi is there a case you also forgot that the numbers could have more or less than 2 digits in the integer part?

Comment: @forpas no just 2 digits

Comment: You can still use division. `X / POWER(1E1, CAST(LOG(X,10) - 1 AS INT))`

Comment: @martin-smith so the result is "An invalid floating point operation occurred"

Comment: @gordon-linoff but when I used this in Select the result is true but how could I use in Update : "  Select Stuff((select [x] from [UTM] order by DESC offset 1 rows fetch next 1rows only),3,0,'.')  "

Comment: So you likely have negative numbers which is another case you have neglected to tell us how to handle. The `STUFF` approach will treat `-` as the first character which I assume is not desired. And you would need `X / POWER(1E1, CAST(LOG(ABS(X),10) - 1 AS INT))`